# Tensorflow=1.12.0 AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'feature_column'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to go through a `Tensorflow` tutorial that uses `tf.feature_column`, however when running it I am encountered with this error.

I have `tensorflow=1.12.0` installed. I am running it on `Python 3.6.8`.

This looks to be the most recent stable package of `tensorflow` and the docs say that Python 3.6 is supported. I have also checked the tensorflow package files and found that `feature_column` is included.

Any idea why this error is still persisting?

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/blakecarroll/SFInsuretech/virtEnv1/tensorflow.py", line 50, in <module>
    categorical_object_feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key=col,hash_bucket_size=1000), dimension = len(df[col].unique())) for col in categorical_columns if df[col].dtype=='O']
  File "/Users/blakecarroll/SFInsuretech/virtEnv1/tensorflow.py", line 50, in <listcomp>
    categorical_object_feat_cols = [tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(key=col,hash_bucket_size=1000), dimension = len(df[col].unique())) for col in categorical_columns if df[col].dtype=='O']
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'feature_column'
```

Comment: Give us the full error please.

Comment: What do you get for `dir(tf)`?

Comment: @HSK this is what dir(tf) returns:

['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'tf']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the name of your script is `tensorflow.py`, which makes `import tensorflow as tf` import your script itself. Rename your script into something else and this should be resolved.